# I can generally sing on-key, but I fear that I'll sing off key in front of the audience. What should I do?

Tags: theory, notation, scales, practice, learning

So I've been wondering that: I can generally sing a song with correct pitches (is it called on-key singing? Sorry, english is not my first language) without guide melody on home.

But throughout my experience of singing, when I go onto stage to sing in front of the crowds I often use a karaoke or music background track with guide melody and It has become my usual habit whenever I sing onto the stage. It was when I was told by my friend to use this if I was afraid to sing on-stage.

But now, when I see other singers, I generally don't compare myself to others unless I'm learning but I'm afraid that if I sing on stage without guide melody like those singers who sing with real-time background instruments performed by musicians, I'll be anxious, and fear (stage fright) that I'll sing off key and everyone will laugh at me.

But actually everytime I usually sing quite well with correct pitches and regular improvisation (not something like r&b or jazz improvisation i mean) when I'm not performing.

What should I do to overcome this off-key stage fright problem? Is it that I actually really can sing without guide melody on-stage so it is just my fear (anxiety)? I see all my friends sing without guide melody on-stage for school work and they go just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Guide melody on karaoke tracks is like stabiliser wheels on a bike. Just do without them - they've become a crutch that you don't need. Listen more carefully to the other instruments on the backing tracks, and align your vocals to them, instead of trying to follow the guide melody. The more you do, the better you'll be, the better you'll feel about your performances.

Comment: What does it mean to align my vocals to it? Is it that I'm already good enough so I dont need guide melody and align my notes to the instruments of the music?

Comment: Without hearing you, I can't tell. But listen way more to certain instruments for pitch control. Only you will decide which they are.